# Different performance for simple update query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database restored on two different machines (developer machine, and tester machine), and whilst not identical they have similar performance.

Using the following query (obfuscated):

```
 CREATE TABLE #TmpTable (MapID int, Primary key(MapID))

 UPDATE MapTable
    SET Tstamp = GetDate() 
   FROM MapTable    
        JOIN Territory as Territory ON Territory.ID = MapTable.TerritoryID
        LEFT JOIN #TmpTable ON #TmpTable.MapID = MapTable.MapID  
  WHERE MapTable.TStamp > DateAdd(year, -100, GETDATE())    
    AND Territory.Name IS NOT null    
    AND Territory.Name NOT LIKE '!%'   
    AND #TmpTable.MapID IS NULL
```

For `400k` records, the developer machine updates in about `4` seconds, but on the tester machine it updates in about `25` seconds; the same DB was restored on both machines.

The problem is that when running this through a tool we use, the timeout for queries is set to `30` seconds and it timeouts `90+ %` of the time on tester machine.

But the execution plan on both is the same...

Can anyone suggest why this is, and possible optimisation(s)?

Comment: Yes they can have different performance on different machines if that was your question.

Comment: If the execution plans are the same maybe it is an IO problem. SSD disk vs. heavily fragmented regular disk?

Comment: Why are you creating a temp table you don't populate? If you just didn't show us that step, consider indexing the temp table to improve performance.

Comment: @HLGEM He mentioned that his code is obfuscated so I assume that temp table is just a place holder for his real, already populated, table.

Comment: The temporary table gets filled during before, the create statement is there just to show the structure. Actually, during the run that the timeout came to our attention, the temp table was empty - no record in it.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I can see that 'might' have an impact on performance is the use of the `GETDATE()` function that might be called twice for each record, but definitely once, so that's 400K calls to the function!

I would put the result of `GETDATE()` into a variable and use that, I always do that unless there is a very good reason no to, for example the changes in the date throughout the query is required like in batch processing within a `CURSOR`.

However, I doubt this will be the main issue with performance. With such a large difference in execution time between the different machines where the execution plan is the same I would be looking at factors external to SQL such as CPU usage, HDD usage, speed and fragmentation etc.

Comment: Also out of date statistics, indexes that need to be rebuilt and potential blocking. Or a need to grow the log during the update on the tester machine.  There are whole books written about what can cause performance problems, sometimes it is the query and sometimes it is the machine environment and sometimes it is the newtork. Personally the tester should be running this on a QA environment server that is simliar to the production server not on his personal local anyway. Performance on a local bears no realtionship to how it will operate in the real life server/network situation.

Comment: [Ref](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx) GETDATE() is a runtime constant. This means that is called just once per statement. The behavior is different if you include GETDATE() into a UDF scalar function. Try select *, getdate() gdt from bigtable